# Shared Git repo syncing to svn causing git svn rebase to pollute repo with a log of no-op merge problems

Tags: git, git-svn

This wasn't so bad at the beginning, but now I have hundreds of no-op merge problems (solved by `git rebase --skip`).

I have setup a shared git repo for my group because it is easier to deal with.  But the company uses SVN so I have to keep SVN in sync with GIT.  Worked like a dream at first, but after weeks of doing this GIT is giving me a lot of the following errors.

```
Applying:  * making all config actions work
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging app/controllers/vulnerabilities_controller.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/controllers/vulnerabilities_controller.rb
Auto-merging public/javascripts/network_analysis_vulnerability_config.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in public/javascripts/network_analysis_vulnerability_config.js
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0046  * making all config actions work
```

My workflow:

```
git co master
git pull origin
git svn rebase
... deal with no-op merge problems ...
git svn dcommit
git pull origin
git push origin
```

The problem is that what is in SVN is the correct so I use `git rebase --skip`, but I have to do that hundreds of times before I can dcommit.

How do I clear these merge problems permanently?

Comment: @bignose: Don't abuse tags, start reading at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list, and others on meta.

Comment: What do you mean by a "no-op" conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this workflow is a good idea at all. Subversion only supports linear history so the branch you synchronize with SVN should not have any merge commits in it. Also, `git svn dcommit` rewrites the commits that are pushed (i.e their SHA changes), which can cause bad things to happen if they have been shared with another repo already. See the CAVEATS section of `git help svn`.

Maybe this kind of workflow could help: http://unethicalblogger.com/posts/2008/10/git_back_subversion_mostly_automagically_part_33